# How can I modify my CSS to require a class instead of a "+ label"?

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
input[type=checkbox] { display:none; } /* to hide the checkbox itself */
input[type=checkbox] + label:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label:before { content: "\f096"; font-size: 16px; } /* unchecked icon */
input[type=checkbox] + label:before { letter-spacing: 10px; } /* space between checkbox and label */

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before { content: "\f046"; font-size: 16px;} /* checked icon */
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before { letter-spacing: 5px; } /* allow space for check mark */
```

How can I change this so that instead of requiring a label before I just need to add a class called "facheck" to the inputs

Comment: `.class_name + label:before` ?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You are applying this CSS to `label:before` - if you don't "require" `label:before`, where is the CSS supposed to be applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add class on lable element if you don't want to use sibling selector:

```
.unchecked {
  content: "\f096"; font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}

.checked {
  content: "\f046"; font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}
```

And then in your HTML:

```
<label class="unchecked"></label>
```

and

```
<label class="checked"></label>
```

I think there is no other way to do that without siblings selector (+). This is what a css says: 'When checkbox is unchecked style following label with this style...'

Comment: Actually you cannot do this, because the selector applies to the label when the checkbox is checked, here you do not take that into consideration

Comment: I added that if he wants to react to checkbox changes this won't work and sibling selector is the only way to do that with only css. Else he has to handle different classes on label him self when checkbox state changes

Comment: Actually I really didn't want to use a label which was what I was trying to find a solution for.

Comment: I suppose you are trying to make your checkboxes a little bit nicer by using this technique but unfortunately you can not style browser checkboxes with custom styling (unless it's chrome) and in order to fake the styling you need to use sibling elements that can be styled according to checkbox state